# Multiple triggers for HTMX?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, htmx

Is it possible to enable multiple trigger types for HTMX? I want to trigger HTMX on either content change or page load. Currently, only the first trigger (`change`) is executed although I include both `change` and `load` in `hx-trigger`:

```html
<select name="area" id="area" hx-post="/api/search" hx-trigger="change load" hx-target="#neighborhood" class="block">
  <option>eby</option>
  <option>nby</option>
  <option>pen</option>
  <option>sfc</option>
  <option>scz</option>
  <option>sby</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Comma-separate your trigger types:

```html
<select name="area" id="area" hx-post="/api/search" hx-trigger="change, load" hx-target="#neighborhood" class="block">
  <option>eby</option>
  <option>nby</option>
  <option>pen</option>
  <option>sfc</option>
  <option>scz</option>
  <option>sby</option>
</select>
```

Comment: its spaces sensitive i think, comma must go immediatly after the event and then space.
like in the above example,dont add extra spaces, at least in my test, didnt work, if not.