# hx-vals in combination with multiple triggers does not have the "event" object attached for both?

Tags: htmx

It is only attatched to the fist one of the multiple triggers.
Here is an example codepen: https://codepen.io/viggiesmalls/pen/NWoRryY

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.6" integrity="sha384-FhXw7b6AlE/jyjlZH5iHa/tTe9EpJ1Y55RjcgPbjeWMskSxZt1v9qkxLJWNJaGni" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        function logEvent(evt) {
          console.log(evt)
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" hx-post="/hx/validate" hx-vals="js:{value: logEvent(event)}" hx-trigger="keyup,change delay:200ms changed" hx-target="next .errors">
<div class="errors"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The exaple above only logs the "event" object on the keyup event, but not on change ( when I click away from the input field)
If I swap change and keyup like this:

```
hx-trigger="change, keyup delay:200ms changed"
```

then the "event" object is only attatched to the change event, and not the keyup event.

Why is that? What would be the correct way to to specify `hx-trigger` in order to have the "event" object attached to both, and a delay of 200ms?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is htmx issue with evaluating js for hx-vals when using delayed triggers.

More details can be found here: https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/1658

The workaround may be to use debounce inside the evaluated js function fo now, until the case is handled properly in the future versions.

Answer (score 1):

You pose a really interesting question.

As [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68403006/multiple-triggers-for-htmx) and [the official docs](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-trigger/) show, it is possible to chain **hx-triggers** as a comma-separated list.

You can also chain them with modifiers, such as the below *(notice you don't need the **changed** modifier with the **change** trigger - that causes issues)*:

```html
<input type="text" hx-post="/hx/validate" 
  hx-trigger="keyup delay:200ms, change delay:200ms" hx-target="next .errors">
```

This should fix most of your problem.

But you'll notice I've removed **hx-vals** from the above code. That's because I think you're listening to 'event' incorrectly here, and misusing hx-vals. **hx-vals** is a shorthand way to send extra info to the server, primarily as JSON. See below from [the docs](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-vals/):

> The hx-vals attribute allows you to add to the parameters that will be submitted with an AJAX request.
> By default, the value of this attribute is a list of name-expression values in JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) format.

If you want to listen to the HTMX event, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74274127/20386689) you should do so like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('htmx:afterRequest', function(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
});
```

So if you put all this together like the below, you should find both triggers successfully work and fire events which you can listen to in the console:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.6" integrity="sha384-FhXw7b6AlE/jyjlZH5iHa/tTe9EpJ1Y55RjcgPbjeWMskSxZt1v9qkxLJWNJaGni" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" hx-post="/hx/validate"
  hx-trigger="keyup delay:200ms changed, change delay:200ms" hx-target="next .errors">
<div class="errors"></div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('htmx:afterRequest', function(evt) {
        console.log(evt);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He's not misusing the the attribute. And he's not trying to listen to an event.